# HTML Form unexpected results within php

Tags: php, html, forms

i've got a create user form which allows new users to be created and added into the database as valid users for my site.

As part of this form, you can select an access level, ie admin, manager, user.
For some reason, no matter what i put here, the new user is always added as level 3 - which is user.
I've read and reread the code and cannot see for the life of me why it is doing this!

Here is the php code which processes the new user request...

```
$accesslv1=$_POST['accesslv'];   //reading the POST variable from the create userpage

//determine what access level this user has
if(accesslv1=="admin") {
    
    $accesslv=1;  //this would be an admim user

} elseif(accesslv1=="manager") {

    $accesslv=2;  //this would be a manager

} else {

    $accesslv=3;  //this would be a user
}
```

for debugging, i popped this at the end instead of a redirect...

```
echo "Username: " .$username . "<br> AccessLevel: " .$accesslv1 ." (lv" .$accesslv .")";
```

and all i get is this...

> Username: test1
>
> AccessLevel: manager (lv3)

This should read manager (lv2), but for whatever reason its not doing!

thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: What is the code of your HTML form?

Comment: If you echo out $accesslv1=$_POST['accesslv']; directly the line afterward. What result do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a few dollar signs in the if/elseif lines

```
if(accesslv1=="admin"){
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the dollar signs for your variables in your code (in your if statements). See below for revision:

```
if($accesslv1=="admin")
{
    $accesslv=1;  //this would be an admim user
}
elseif($accesslv1=="manager")
{
    $accesslv=2;  //this would be a manager
}
```

Answer (score 0):

review below:

`$accesslv1=$_POST['accesslv'];`  but `if(accesslv1=="admin")`